# How do you generate an expired Facebook Access Token for testing?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

We are trying to update our app and server to handle the upcoming [Facebook offline_access deprecation](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/).  However, we're having trouble testing it since we can't find an easy way to generated an expired access token.

We've tried using the [Graph API Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me) to create an access token but change a character in it. However this just results in an invalid token instead of a valid expired token.

I'm shocked Facebook hasn't provided a way to do this to facilitate testing.  So I'm just assuming I've missed some straightforward way to do this, so would appreciate a pointer from someone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you generate an `access_token` and then change your password, it will auto-expire the token.